# Java JUnit: Reset SSLContext in JUnit Test

Tags: java, ssl, junit, dependency-injection

I'm writing some methods to manipulate the SSLContext. I wrote JUnit-Test to test the functionality. Unfortunately I'm stuck, because I can't find a way to reset the SSLContext. So I have to run every test on it's own within it's own JVM, because the affect of previous test will affect the next test. The SSLContext seams not to be resetable, because it is not written in a DI manner.

Is there a way to reset the SSLContext?

Is there a way to run every JUnit-Test in its own JVM? (I use Maven as Build-Management-Tool)

<s>This won't work</s> This will only partly work:

```
SSLContext defaultSSLContext = SSLContext.getDefault();

// manipulate SSLContext

SSLContext.setDefault(defaultSSLContext);
```

**Edit 2017-02-02**

**My Java Installation was broken**

My Java installtion was broken, so in my case the default SSLContext was null `(null == SSLContext.getDefault())`. So I could not set the SSLContext. The method raises a NullPointerException. I reinstalled Java and now the SSLContext is working again and the default SSLContext will not be null.

**Reseting the SSLContext**

Storing the SSLContext in an interim variable and restoring it afterwards will work for the SSLContext. But not for implementation like java.net.URL. These implementations seam to keep a Singleton instance of the SSLContext from the first call and will never change it during the runtime of the JVM.

**JUnit forked Run with Maven**

I followed *Stefan Birkner's* proposal and used Maven Surefire Plugin.

I added in the project pom.xml:

```
</plugins>
    [...]
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
            <forkCount>2</forkCount>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I split the JUnit Test into parts, that could run on their own without interfering. So `FooTest.java` became `Foo01Test.java ... Foo03Test.java`. Now the tests are running within Eclipse and with Maven.

Comment: When writing *UnitTests* then you should mock the `SSLContext` so that no reset is needed.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: Unfortunately this is not possible in my case, because I test by accessing a server, if the update of the SSLContext works as expected. A third party library is involved, which does not support individual SSLContext or SSLFactories, so I have to update the default SSLContext.

Comment: *"Unfortunately this is not possible in my case, because I test by accessing a server"* then you are doing *acceptance testing* that's OK. But you should also have *unittest* to verify that your own code works correctly. These *unittests* should mock any class that does not belong to your own code (at least).

Comment: Which build tool do you use for running the tests? Maven, Ant, Gradle, ....

Comment: @StefanBirkner I use Maven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Maven Surefire Plugin allows you to specify that a new JVM is used for each test: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html